# Google Geolocation API returns IP location even if considerIp:false

Tags: google-api, geolocation, google-geocoding-api, google-geolocation

I wanted to test the [Google Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro?hl=en) but I figured something strange.

I have run a basic request script on my machine and on repl.it, the results are correlated to the IP location of the machine. (even tried through VPN, same results)

It seems that Google is not taking the considerIp:false into account.

Even with a fake mac address, I got a 200 response (not a 404 as described in the end of the doc page).

Any positive experience on your side?

---

My script:

```
import requests

url='https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=xxx'


response = requests.post(url, data="""{
  "considerIp": "false",
  "wifiAccessPoints": [
    {
        "macAddress": "00:25:9c:cf:1c:ac",
        "signalStrength": -43,
        "signalToNoiseRatio": 0
    }
  ]
}""")

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

try sending a JSON in order to specify the content-application type, worked for me. Also you need to have at least 2 wifi access points to avoid fallbacking to IP geolocation.

```
response = requests.post(url, json={
  "considerIp": "false",
  "wifiAccessPoints": [
    {
        "macAddress": "00:25:9c:cf:1c:ac",
        "signalStrength": -43,
        "signalToNoiseRatio": 0
    },
    {
        "macAddress": "bb:aa:bb:aa:bb:aa",
        "signalStrength": -43,
        "signalToNoiseRatio": 0
    }
  ]
})
```